# Track a click on a button that doesn't do anything with GTM

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, dom-events, google-tag-manager, event-tracking

I see a ton of write ups for tracking events when a button does something like, take you to a new page or a form submission but I can't find anything for a button that does nothing. I've successfully set up tracking for form submissions but I have a specific button that just copies some code to the clipboard that I want to track, I can't seem to get it to track using similar methods to form submission tracking.

Any ideas?

I would be open to tracking how many clicks the button gets an alternative way to GTM/GA.

Answer (score 0):

With click tracking you can track anything, not only buttons that do something. Actually you can track even how many people are clicking on some text, or image. All you need to do is to set a trigger for "All Elements" clicks:

[image]

Set the Fire On as usual - using class, id or CSS selector.
After that you just need to setup a tag using this as trigger:

[image]

The category/action/label fields could be anything you want for easy recognition.

Set the "Non-interaction Hit" as true, if you don't want the clicks to count as interaction (affecting your bounce rate).

With this you can set a click tracking for absolutely everything on your website, no matter if there is any action when you click it or no.